# How to use multiple select in DropDown?

Tags: ios, swift

I use [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) library
Single selection work perfect
But i dont know how to config it for multiple select.
I try to use this [code](https://gist.github.com/nvdmcs/74de7e2d7e17aa3eb6f6192d7a763b45).
But when i press button `dropdown` doesnt show, just show print.

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("test")
    dropdownManager.open()
}
```

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Quick look at that GitHub repo... the Demo app has a multi-select drop-down already - it's the "Choose an article" drop-down.

Comment: @DonMag, Yes, you are right. Thank you